# Há uma "sintaxe" para endereços?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Não sei se essa pergunta tem muito a ver com o português, mas é algo que sempre quis saber.

Endereços de estabelecimentos ou residências geralmente contém o logradouro, número, complemento (se houver), bairro, cidade, CEP e estado, todos separados por vírgulas e/ou traços. 
Mas há alguma ordem específica oficial e alguma definição de em que partes se separa com vírgula ou traço?

Exemplos:

> Rua Fritz Jacobs, 1236 - Boa Vista, São José do Rio Preto - SP, 15025-500

e

> Rua Espanha, 399, Jardim Novo Mundo
>   São José Do Rio Preto - SP, 15084-080

No primeiro endereço os itens são separados alternadamente por vírgula e traço. Peguei esse endereço pelo Google Maps.
Já no segundo, o traço é usado apenas para separar a cidade do estado, e há uma quebra de linha separando o bairro e a cidade. Esse peguei de um [site de endereços](http://www.apontador.com.br/local/sp/sao_jose_do_rio_preto/alimentos_e_bebidas/7YFDA69Q/supermercado_laranjao.html).
Nesse caso, os dois endereços seguem a mesma ordem, porém o uso da vírgula e traço se diferem.

Comment: O site dos [**Correios**](http://www.correios.com.br/para-voce/precisa-de-ajuda/como-enderecar-cartas-e-encomendas) tem instruções, mas que ainda deixam ainda assim algumas dúvidas.

Comment: Os endereços não tem sintaxe, só estilos diferentes.

Comment: Pessoalmente, vou do mais.geral ao mais específico,.como."São Paulo, São Caetano, Catorze de Junho, Rua Alberto Fraghari, 765". Mas,.como disse Centaurus, não há regra, só o sofrimento do carteiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruno, pode ser que a ABNT tenha estabelecido diretrizes sobre o leiaute de endereços mas nada encontrei em sua página. Os correios do Brasil tem suas normas, que você encontra [**aqui**](http://www.correios.com.br/para-sua-empresa/servicos-para-o-seu-contrato/guias/enderecamento/arquivos/Guia_Enderecamento.pdf), mas o que acontece na prática é:

> - correspondência comercial - utiliza-se o padrão da empresa.
> - correspondencia pessoal - aqui a coisa vira uma zona total. Cada um escreve como quer. Ninguém segue normas.